# read all filename in directory containing emojis

Tags: r, directory, emoji, tm

I want to read all file names in a directory which contain some emojis. For instance:

'❤️Geschenk für Sie!❤️.msg'
'Für Ungeduldige! .msg'
'Trockene Haut ❄️?.msg'

I've already tried `dir("./")` and `tm::DirSource("./", encoding = "UTF-8")`

`dir("./")` can read the filenames but returns `??` instead for the emojis.

```
> dir("./")
[1] "??Geschenk für Sie!??.msg" "Für Ungeduldige! ??.msg"      "Trockene Haut ???.msg"
```

And an error occurs with the latter one

```
> tm::DirSource("./", encoding = "UTF-8")
Error in tm::DirSource(path.newsletter, encoding = "UTF-8") : 
  non-existent or non-readable file(s): ./??Geschenk für Sie!??.msg ./Für Ungeduldige! ??.msg ./Trockene Haut ???.msg
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you want a) read the file names? use `list.files()`. b) want to read the messages? Because you are asking about a, but doing b.

Comment: I want to do both.